# Linking a slicer to multiple pivot tables using office scripts

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I'm trying to add a slicer to connect to multiple pivot tables in Excel using office scripts. It seems like the office scripts can only connect 1 slicer to 1 pivot table. The recording action does not seem to be able to record the connectivity action in the pivot table slicer settings.

```
  let newSlicer = workbook.addSlicer(newPivotTable, newPivotTable.getHierarchy("Overdue").getFields()[0], selectedSheet);
```

The above script does not seem to be able to pass in more than one pivot table. Anyone got a solution to this? Much appreciation.

Comment: Do the PivotTables read from the same source table? If so, you perhaps you can try connecting the slicer to that and seeing if it will filter the PivotTables

Comment: Yes, for this case all pivot tables are from the same source. Manual work connecting the slicer works fine. But what I need is via office scripts.

Comment: This may not be supported. In VBA, when you add additional PivotTables to the slicer, they're added to the SlicerCache. It doesn't look like either Office Scripts or Office.js have a SlicerCache object. I found a workaround. But I'm not sure if it will work for your situation. I'll post my code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think linking multiple PivotTables to a slicer is currently supported. But there may be a workaround. You can run the Office Scripts code below. You will have to update the variables with the names for your own PivotTable, field for the slicer, etc.:

```js
    function main(workbook:ExcelScript.Workbook){
      let sh: ExcelScript.Worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
      let slicer1: ExcelScript.Slicer = getOrAddSlicer("PivotTable1","Col1",workbook);
      let slicer2: ExcelScript.Slicer = getOrAddSlicer("PivotTable1", "Col2", workbook);
    }
    
    function getOrAddSlicer(ptName:string,ptRowHierarchyName: string, workbook:ExcelScript.Workbook): ExcelScript.Slicer {
      let sh: ExcelScript.Worksheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
      let pt: ExcelScript.PivotTable = sh.getPivotTable(ptName);
      let pf: ExcelScript.PivotField = pt.getRowHierarchy(ptRowHierarchyName).getPivotField(ptRowHierarchyName);
      let slicer: ExcelScript.Slicer = workbook.getSlicer(ptRowHierarchyName);
      if (slicer === undefined) {
        slicer = workbook.addSlicer(pt, pf, sh);
      }
      return slicer;
    }
```

The getOrAddSlicer function will add a slicer to the active worksheet. Or select a slicer on the active sheet that's linked to a specific field if it's previously been added. After you've added all the slicers, you can copy and paste the PivotTable the slicers are linked to. After you've copied and pasted the PT, both PivotTables should also be linked to all of the slicers.

Comment: This is the code that the recorder generates which will have 4 slicers appearing on the screen. 

let newSlicer = workbook.addSlicer(newPivotTable, newPivotTable.getHierarchy("Date").getFields()[0], sheet1);
let newSlicer1 = workbook.addSlicer(newPivotTable, newPivotTable.getHierarchy("Name").getFields()[0], sheet1);
let newSlicer2 = workbook.addSlicer(newPivotTable1, newPivotTable1.getHierarchy("Date").getFields()[0], sheet1);
let newSlicer3 = workbook.addSlicer(newPivotTable1, newPivotTable1.getHierarchy("Name").getFields()[0], sheet1);

Comment: What I wanted is 2 slicers, each slicer able to connect to the 2 pivot tables. So based on your code, how do I changed to workaround?

Comment: If you want to link multiple slicers to a PivotTable, you would follow a similar process. You first have to add all of the slicers you want associated with the PivotTable. After you do that, copy and paste the PivotTable so you have two PTs. I will update my code to show what this might look like.